# My do while loop is only executing once

Tags: c++, c, loops, while-loop, continue

I have made a sample code in c.

```
do
{


 switch(i)
 {

 case 1:
 {
   cout<< "1\n";
   break;

 }
 case 2:
 {
      cout<< "1\n";
      break;
  }
  case 3:
  {
    continue;
  }


 }
 }while (0);
```

Here in this code if value of i is 3 then i want to restart the do while loop which will result in an infinite loop. But unfortunately loop is not getting executed again. What will be the reason for that.?
I have checked the assembly code in visual studio of the same code and found that there is no JMP statement in the assembly for continue statement inside switch -case .

Comment: `continue` jumps over the rest of the loop body and re-tests the condition.  Yours is hardcoded `false` (after conversion of `0` to `bool`).  Given the other cases `break` anyway - leaving the loop, you could use `while (true)` instead (assuming your real code is substantially different).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because either it is about a typo or OP is missing knowledge of a very basic part of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while (0)` means it will fall out the bottom of the loop.  Even if you have `continue` the condition is re-eval'd

Comment: I have checked the assembly code in visual studio of the same code and found that there is no JMP statement in the assembly for continue statement inside switch -case .

Comment: @kernel If it's the final case it doesn't need to jump anywhere.

Comment: As all the continue is doing is jumping to the next statement the optimizer is probably removing it from the generated assembler code as it is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `continue` inside a `do-while` loop, it jumps at the evaluation at the bottom, that is always false in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are explaining `continue` but it looks from your comments like you understand how that works.

> if value of i is 3 then i want to restart the do while loop which will result in an infinite loop

The code is functioning as you describe - it is jumping to the 'while' condition on `i==3`. The only difference is that if you want an infinite loop you need `while(1)` not `while(0)`.